# Real part of $cis (\theta)$

Tags: complex-numbers

[image]

I have a question on a proof regarding this: The question is "Show this is true," although I am not sure if the last minus sign should be an equal sign, or else it doesn't make sense.

I know that this is related to De Moivre's theorem and Euler's theorem. I tried just solving for the real part of

$$1-\frac{1}{2}e^{i\theta}+\frac{1}{4}e^{2i\theta}-\frac{1}{8}e^{3i\theta}+\cdots $$

And as this is a infinite geometric series, I was thinking this might be finding the real part of the sum of infinity. As $e^{i\theta}$ is equivalent to $cos (\theta) + i sin(\theta)$, it could lead me to proving the answer, but I only got $\frac{2}{2+cos \theta}$.

Could anyone advise me on what I did wrong, and what I could do? 
Thank you in advance! 
Sorry for any wrong tags or title labelling. Working on those!

Comment: Just slight wondering...typo in $\frac{1}{4}cos$ term where there might be a 2 in front of the angle?

Comment: @imranfat, I thought so too! But not too sure...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Yep, jumped the gun. :)

Comment: *Please* write the formula in MathJax, the image might dissapear from under MSE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As commented, the $\frac14\cos(\theta)$ must be a typo for $\frac14\cos(2\theta)$.

Yes, the sum of the series with the complex exponential is $2/(2+e^{i\theta})$. But the real part of that is not what you think. The real part of $2/z$ is not $2/\Re z$. You need to rationalize  the denominator to find the real part: $$\frac{2}{2+e^{i\theta}}
=\frac{2}{2+e^{i\theta}}\frac{2+e^{-i\theta}}{2+e^{-i\theta}}
=\dots=\frac{4+2e^{-i\theta}}{5+4\cos(\theta)}.$$

You can take the real part of *that* by taking the real part of the *numerator*, and you get something very close to what the problem says. Now consider we've already spotted two typos in the problem... (**Edit** Come to think of it, we can easily check the answer by considering $\theta=0$, and sure enough the sum given in the problem is off by a factor of $2$.)